# Install NewRelic mobile agent for Android application

Tags: android, newrelic

I am trying to install NewRelic's mobile agent for Android app. I followed their instructions, and have set up NEWRELIC_HOME (pointing to agent directory) and ANDROID_HOME (pointing to Android SDK location). When I run nrandroid-setup from the app's directory (as suggested), I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: com.newrelic.agent.install.Main.  Program will exit.
error: java returned a non-zero status code
```

I have watched their install video, and it is very simple, so not sure why my installation does not work (only difference, I run under 64-bit Windows 7, they are using Mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, all the things that Toby said and also check the Java version you are running. In my case, I could not build with java 1.6.0_32, it only worked when I upgraded to version 1.7.0_13

Answer (score 4):

I think you might have opened a ticket with New Relic already, but in previous instances this problem was resolved by checking your environment variables and updating the SDK (I include updating the New Relic monitoring SDK for good measure but it's not likely to be the cause)

1) Verify that you've declared NEWRELIC_HOME and ANDROID_HOME, generally by running an 'export' command to make sure both are declared. Then make sure you can navigate based on those variables and see they lead to the right place. Please include the results of 'export' in your reply if you're still having trouble.

in PowerShell use `Get-ChildItem Env:`

in Terminal use `export`

from cmd use `SET`

2) Update your Android SDK

To update the ADT plugin for Eclipse to the latest version, follow these steps:

Select Help > Software Updates > Find and Install....

Select Search for updates of the currently installed features and press Finish.

If any update for ADT is available, select and install.

3) Make sure you have the latest version of New Relic for Mobile Apps for Android.

The newest version of our Android agent is available by logging in at rpm.newrelic.com and going to Mobile>"See Instructions" or "Add a new mobile app"

Notably, the Android SDK isn't listed on our requirements page, we're just realizing that this has caused some users trouble, and I do think that step 2) will resolve the problem. I'm also going to update our documentation with that requirement once we've got it all tested and verified.

Comment: thanks Toby, yes, I talked to Hollie. I finally figured out what were the issues (in my response)

Comment: it helped me a lot too but i'm still getting an error: "unknown or invalid android build target: android - 16" I've added a question, if you could help me I'd really appreciate it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744226/new-relic-on-android-4-2-2

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your android sdk it may be becoz your android sdk_> tools->sdklibs.jar have no logger class please change the sdk with latest i have change the sdk and solve my problem.

Comment: That is what I basically ended up doing - updating to the latest possible version of Android SDK