# New Relic on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, newrelic

So I'm getting an error when doing the new relic's setup on android in windows 7 64 bits. After I run the setup.exe and give the project's path it throws the following error:

```
Unknown or invalid android build target: android - 16
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? I've updated the SDKs and java but still nothing. Also the enviroment variables are all set

Also this happens AFTER I've put my token

Comment: It seems that you solved this problem. Would you like to answer yourself how to did it? It would be of great help for me. Thanks.

Comment: done, I meesed up the eclipse's sdk with windows's sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confused the eclipse's SDK with the Windows's SDK. You need to open the SDK on the eclipse button, not on the windows start menu

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to file a ticket with New Relic support if you haven't already: support@newrelic.com

Regarding your specific question -- you might want to verify that the `target` property in your `project.properties` is `android-16` (no spaces!).

If changing that doesn't help, please do hit up support!

Comment: If that doesn't work, try reinstalling Eclipse and the SDK outside of the protected "program files" or equivalent folder on Windows 7 because the security on Windows 7 usually interferes if those are placed in there.

Comment: By the way, when you say you updated Java, I hope you didn't update to Java 7. For Android, you can only go up to Oracle JDK SE 6 only, not 7.

Comment: Yes, I already solved this, the problem was I updated the android-sdk from windows, not eclipse! but thanks for the support